# заполнение df случайными числами

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Есть исходный df следующего вида:

| id | numer | city |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | Moscow |
| 2 | 5 | Tula |
| 3 | 3 | Ivanovo |
| 4 | 1 | Vladimir |

Хочется написать код, который добавит строчки к этому df, по принципу отсутствующего значения в столбце numer, число думал брать методом `np.random.randint()`.

то есть я вызываю:

```
np.random.randint(10, size=6)
```

получаю некоторый список значений , допустим `[1,4,6,8,7,3]` далее сравниваю с df['numer'] и если такого числа в столбце нет - то добавлю новую строку с номером из рандома ( в этом случае 6,8,7),

то есть 3 строчки . Столбец city оставить пустым, либо заполнить рандомным названием из списка

> `['Kursk','Órel', 'Tambov', 'Voronezh']`

, должно получится следующее:

| id | numer | city |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | Moscow |
| 2 | 5 | Tula |
| 3 | 3 | Ivanovo |
| 4 | 1 | Vladimir |
| 5 | 6 | Órel |
| 6 | 8 | Tambov |
| 7 | 7 | Tambov |

Что я сделал:

```
b =np.random.randint(10, size=6) #генерация списка рандомных чисел
dff =pd.DataFrame(b, columns =['rand']) #преобразование в формат dataframe
```

и собственно добавление (df - исходный data frame):

```
for i in dff['rand']:
if i not in df['Numera']:
    df['Numera'].append(i)
```

но это не работает. До добавления города из списка я даже не дошел.

И еще вопрос, а как в df добавлять новые строчки, только с одним элементом ( пустые элементы nan видимо), например такого вида:

| id | numer | city |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  | 10 |  |

Из всего что я видел -все методы предполагают заполнять все строго обязательно ( и number и city), а если один какой то только ( в данном случае numer) ?

Comment: Нельзя добавлять что-то только в один столбец. Можно добавлять только строчки целиком в датафрейм через `pd.concat`, например.

Comment: зачем создавать и потом еще сравнивать, и только потом вставлять те, что не совпали. можно узнать изначально те, что есть и создавать из другого диапазона.

Comment: _'Столбец city оставить пустым, либо заполнить рандомным названием из списка'_ , а чем тогда заполняется столбец id?